# Remote debugger for Linux from one VM (IDA) to another (running the debuggee)

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, linux, remote

I want to debug a Linux program (ELF), but my IDA Pro is on a Windows 10 VM and I want to use remote debugging to debug the program on Ubuntu (also in a VM).

So, is it possible to debug if both machines are VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can actually debug remotely using 2 Virtual Machines as long as they have network connection.

Just copy the server file in the dbgsrv folder from IDA directory and choose what type of architecture you will debug.

[image]

[image]

Just make sure you have to change the permission of the file to executable using chmod +x

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done the remote debug server and fill requirement for input file,input  folder, ip, and password but the error said " it can find the path of the input file". It is have to do with vm isolation features?